# How to find out what image version is installed on QNX?

Tags: qnx, neutrino

I am trying to find out what image version is installed on a QNX box.

Checking this link: http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino_utilities%2Fp%2Fprocnto.html

I went into /sbin/ and had a look in there but there aren't any binaries I can see that would provide this information.

I attempted to run the command `pci -v` which printed a lot of system info, but no image version/information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
uname -a
```

More info here: http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.0.0/index.html#com.qnx.doc.neutrino.utilities/topic/u/uname.html